# Оператор присваивания

Tags: c++

Почему в операторе присваивания мы возвращаем `*this`, а не просто `this`?

```
Matrix & Matrix::operator =(const Matrix& m2) {
    if (this != &m2) {
        (Matrix(m2)).swap(*this);
    }
    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator +(const Matrix &m2) {
    if (m2.columns != this->columns || m2.rows != this->rows) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    Matrix temp(this->rows, this->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->columns; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = m2.matrix[i][j] + this->matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Потому что `Matrix&` - это `*this`, а `Matrix*` - это `this` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возвращать из оператора присваивания вы можете что угодно (или вообще ничего). Главное, чтобы в операторе присваивания, как и в любой другой функции, тип значения, указанного в `return`, совпадал с (или был приводим к) типу возврата, указанного в объявлении функции.

Вы же сами написали, что ваш оператор присваивания имеет тип возврата `Matrix &`. Это значит, что в `return` вам придется указывать lvalue типа `Matrix`. `*this` таким lvalue является, а `this` - не является.

Тем не менее никто вам не запрещает написать оператор присваивания, который будет возвращать, например, `Matrix *`. В таком операторе присваивания вы можете возвращать `this`:

```
Matrix *Matrix::operator =(const Matrix& m2) {
  ...
  return this;
}
```

Это будет весьма *странным* типом возврата для оператора присваивания, но ничего нелегального тут нет.

Другими словами, что вы сами указали в типе возврата функции - то и возвращайте. Так что вопрос о том, почему в вашем случае возвращать надо именно `*this` - это вопрос именно к вам. Вы сами так захотели.

Comment: Вот Вы говорите, что использовать указатели вместо ссылок, в этом ничего плохого нет. Но все-таки целесообразно использовать ссылки. А почему? Напрмиер я так сделал:                                            
Sto* operator=(const Sto* ob)
 {
   
  if (this == ob)
  return this;
   
  if (data) delete[] data;
   
  size=ob->size;
  sign=ob->sign;
   
  data=new int[size]; 
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  data[i]=ob->data[i];

  return this;
 }

Answer (score 5):

Потому что мы возвращаем ссылку на объект типа `Matrix`, а `this` -- указатель. Чтобы возвращать не указатель на объект, а сам объект мы разыменовываем указатель (это делается как раз с помощью оператора `*`). Поэтому и `*this`.

---

Возвращать значение осмысленно, например, потому, что мы сможем писать множественное присваивание:

```
class Foo{
     public:
    int x;
    Foo & operator=(const Foo& other) {
        x = other.x;
        return *this;
    }
    Foo(int a=0) {
        x = a;
    }
};
```

После этого можно будет написать:

```
Foo a,b,c;
a = b = c = 2;
```

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что благодаря использованию *this в качестве возвращаемого объекта, мы возвращаем непосредственно его значения, а не адрес ?

Comment: @John Да, ровно так.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос еще реализацию оператора сложения, почему здесь мы возвращаем просто объект temp и не прибегаем к разыменовыванию? я так понимаю  потому что temp не является ссылкой верно?

Comment: @John нет. Не совсем. temp -- обычная переменная типа Matrix. Поэтому мы возвращаем просто этот объект. (На самом деле temp --объект локальный и живёт только внутри вызова функции, поэтому мы возвращаем его копию). Но никаких действий с ним производить не надо.  А разыменновывать нужно указатели, а не ссылки. Это две разных сущности. Условно указатель -- адрес, по которому хранится переменная. А ссылка -- альтернативное имя для этой переменной. Можете попробовать что-то прочитать по этому поводу.

Comment: @John, нет, мы возвращаем ссылку (`*this`).